# Lock Auth0 for android not returning UserProfile on authentication

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, locking, auth0

I'm using Lock for providing Login functionality in my android App to users.

Here is my code:
    private Lock lock;

```
private LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager;

private BroadcastReceiver authenticationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String idToken = intent.getStringExtra("com.auth0.android.lock.extra.IdToken");
        String tokenType = intent.getStringExtra("com.auth0.android.lock.extra.TokenType");
        Log.i(TAG, "User  logged in with " + idToken + " "+ tokenType);
    }
};

//Not sure use of this callback  though its not being called anytime.
private LockCallback callback = new AuthenticationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthentication(Credentials credentials) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Authenticated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Authentication cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(LockException error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Authentication Error");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Auth0 auth0 = new Auth0(getString(R.string.auth0_clientId), getString(R.string.auth0_domain));
    this.lock = Lock.newBuilder(auth0, callback)
            .build();
    broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    broadcastManager.registerReceiver(authenticationReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.auth0.android.lock.action.Authentication"));
    startActivity(this.lock.newIntent(this));
}
```

I have following two questions:
1). First of all I don't understand why it needs callback though it doesn't callback even after authentication succeeded.
2). Shouldn't LocalBroadcastManager get response with UserProfile information instead of token information?

I'm using Lock version: com.auth0.android:lock:2.0.0-beta.2

Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried answer?

Comment: No i am using another version of android:lock

Answer (score 2):

have you tried onSuccess method? I cant see in your code, that's why it's not executing after successful attempt.

Override `onSuccess` method in your `LockCallback callback`, this will return UserProfile.

```
/**
 * Callback for authentication API calls to Auth0 API.
 */
public interface AuthenticationCallback extends Callback {

    /**
     * Called when authentication is successful.
     * It might include user's profile and token information.
     * @param profile User's profile information or null.
     * @param token User's token information (e.g. id_token).
     */
    void onSuccess(UserProfile profile, Token token);

}
```

#### [Source](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.Android/blob/aae426ca611bcbc3a15a5ef9a98d7408851a6bbb/core/src/main/java/com/auth0/api/callback/AuthenticationCallback.java)